# Lion: Dock settings revert after logging out or restarting

Tags: macos, settings, reboot

I'm having problem with my user account in Lion. I want to remove some of the icons in the dock. Every time I sign out the dock will be "restored". Not to factory settings but always to the same appearance. I'm not really sure if this behaviour started when I upgraded Snow Leopard or before. Upgrading to Lion did not solve the problem. The behaviour even applies to some general settings and some Application. Adjustments just wont survive reboot.

To me, it feels like some permission glitch?

- New user accounts works fine
- Using the disk utility, repair permission didn't solve the problem
- Clearing the Libary/Chache didn't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really think it has to do with this issue https://discussions.apple.com/message/15844450#15844450 (Problem deleting files - Lion prompts for password)

After I changed the permissions for my home dir (follow the link) things looks and works ok. Time will tell if there is more to it, hopefully not.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: people come here for a separate answer, otherwise they can browse apple support. (its down atm)

Answer (score 3):

Yes this sounds like a permissions problem - probably the permissions on the Dock's settings files are wrong.

The easiest way to fix it is to delete these files. You'll find the config file at

~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist

Make a change to the dock and it will then regenerate them with the correct permissions. Do note that you shouldn't lose your Dock settings this way, but it is a possibility. In any case, the Dock is easy to configure back the way you want it.

If that doesn't work, try deleting:

~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.db

as well.

Hint: A clue that the permissions on them are wrong is if OS X prompts for a password when you try to delete these files - it shouldn't.

Comment: Im pretty sure this "bigger" than just the dock. Changing screen saver dose not stick either. And files (in the GUI) added to Vuze disappear after reboot.

I could only locate com.apple.dockfixup.plist

Comment: Ok, I was looking in wrong Libary/Preferences, files located and deleted. The dock works fine from what I can tell. But changing the reverse scroll dose not stick... Any clues?

Comment: It sounds like you have a general permissions issue with your preferences Folder. The GUI Program Batchmod as recommended by MacAttack below, can help you change the permissions of the files to the correct ones - you must be the owner of the files. 

If you are happy with command line utilities, you can use the command chown to accomplish the same thing.